# Looping in Adobe Flash Professional CS6

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs6, adobe-flash-cs3

I'm trying to create a animation and there's a asset that's repeatedly looped, hence I have to change it to a single-frame loop. I need help on how to find the looping window.

Ive been trying to find the "Looping" Window, but it isn't appearing in my properties.